# vb.net: 64 bit application with win32 interop

Tags: vb.net, interop, 64-bit

I have a huge application that uses external components.
Some of these external components are not actively maintained. 
I can interop them, but they are then still win32 components.
I hope I expressed myself correctly.

Can I then still compile my application for 64 bit, or am I doomed to staying at 32 bit because my external components do not support 64?

Thank you!

Comment: This is way too vague, you'll have to describe those components.  Odds are not good, if they are COM components then hosting in a surrogate process may be possible.

Comment: I have about 20 of them, so I guess describing each and everyone' features might not really help. These are not some funky add-ons that I included for fun, but they are 3rd-party-components that are really needed for my app to function. Most of them control some specific hardware.

Comment: I guess I am really doomed.
I want to use the System.Speech.Synthesis. 
If I change my project to x86 to allow COM Interop, it is giving me a FormatException on this line:         

 Dim m_Synth As New SpeechSynthesizer
         For Each v As InstalledVoice In m_Synth.GetInstalledVoices
              Debug.Print(v.VoiceInfo.Name)
         Next  

So it seems I am really dooomed.
I am caught in a vicious circle...

Comment: Using the SpeechSynthesizer class in 32-bit code is not a problem.  You are just using the wrong Debug method, it will fall over with a FormatException when the voice name contains something like {0}.  Use Debug.WriteLine() instead.  And practice using a debugger, this should have been easy to see by just inspecting the Name property.

Comment: @Hans Passant Hmmm, when I switch to extended compiler settings and set it to x86, it stops with the above error anyway. Here is my code: Imports System.Speech.Synthesis

Public Class Form1

    Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load

        Dim m_Synth As New SpeechSynthesizer
        For Each v As InstalledVoice In m_Synth.GetInstalledVoices
            ' Debug.WriteLine(v.VoiceInfo.Name)
        Next

    End Sub
End Class

Comment: I will move this to a new question because it seems that it doesn't really have to do with 64 bit only (although it happens only at 64 bit for me)

Comment: Last year, we migrated a VB project to VB.NET and x64. It had various COM and ActiveX dependencies. We configured the COM dependencies to operate out of process, but the ActiveX controls required recompiling for x64.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it is just like you said. 64-bit application can only have 64-bit components. To have 32-bit code, it has to be compiled to 32-bits.

I had this problem a lot of times with Crystal Reports and Microsoft Office. Office already exists in 64, but still these applications are doomed because of 32-bit Crystal Reports, because there isn't another.

Comment: 32-bit COM components can be run out-of-process. 32-bit ActiveX controls will need x64 versions, unless they can be activated as local servers. (We did that with one.)